# Skin under bulla hurt when in contact with water

Tags: dermatology, blister

I've conducted a case study with one contender and found out that interestingly, torn blisters (a large bulla in my case) burn when in contact with plain water.

I really am talking about plain water, not alcohol, disinfectant, hydrogen peroxide (which shouldn't be applied to blisters) or else.

Why is this the case? I suspect it's fairly similar to having any part of the skin torn away and sprinkling water on it, but luckily, this has not yet happened to me.

Comment: Sensor nerve endings not yet habituated to new chemical stimuluses, closer to the outside environment? Please elaborate on conditions.

Comment: @LangLangC The case study and all that was a bit tongue-in-cheek. Well, I've went hiking in the alps and, as one tends to do, got myself a blister. It tore, I had to shower or be expelled from the group otherwise and when the water touched the blister, it burned a bit. Until know, I've kept thinking about why this could be the case

Comment: Plain water is hypotonic, so cells would absorb it via osmosis. Perhaps cellular swelling stimulates pain receptors.

Comment: @CareyGregory Wouldn't osmosis take too long to explain the *immediate* sensation?

Comment: @CareyGregory That might actually be a pretty good starting point. In the lower dermis, which would be exposed if epidermis is torn away by blister, there are the Ruffini corpuscles (a type of pain receptors), who respond to a quick change of pressure. That's just educated guessing on my part though...

Comment: I've thought about this one before as well (beyond her share of blisters, someone may have had to irrigate in tap water after she smashed the skin of her pinky off when pounding in tent stakes with a rock?) and I'm going to go with @CareyGregory on this one, as the dermis is full of nociceptor nerve endings and changes in tonicity likely are registered as noxious stimuli.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Feel free to expand that into an answer, if your schedule allows this.